# How to save only the date in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have mapped a property with the Java.util.Date type to a table column in a MySQL database. It saves the whole date/time! How can I make hibernate to save only the Date and not the time.
My mapping is:

```
    <property name="registrationDate" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="regDate" length="10" />
    </property>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must have specified your column as DateTime type in your table. Just make it a Date type column. So only the date portion will be stored.

EDIT:

If you are using table auto generation you can define your java.util.date as follows;

```
@Temporal(DATE)
protected java.util.Date endDate;
```

if you are using xml configuration it can be defined as follows;

```
<basic name="myDate"/>
<temporal>DATE</temporal>
</basic>
```

Comment: But the table has been generated by hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto. I haven't created the table myself. I might want to drop the table 1000 times during the debuging... It is so dirty to change it in the database! Are you sure there is no other solution?

Comment: @user1892555..try with `java.sql.Date`

Comment: You can use java.util.date as well. Just see my edit and it should work for you.

Comment: @dinukadev , I tried same case in HIbernate 5.x , still unable to save only date.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only date of to day, you can use.
In Mapping class:

```
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="ROW_DATE", length=7)
    public Date getMyDate() {
        return this.rowDate;
}
```

If you need date and time, you can use.
In Mapping class:

```
 @Column(name="ROW_DATE")
    public Date getMyDate() {
        return rowDate;
    }
```